# cpu 100%, and js heap keep growing until the page crashes

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, vuejs3

Occasionally, when the website is running, it may appear cpu 100%, and js heap keep growing until the page crashes, console no new error. The front-end framework is vue3 + webpack5. Due to the large amount of code, it is not clear where the problem is caused by reading the code. It is now completely unclear what is causing the problem. Sometimes, even without doing anything, observing the website for about ten minutes can suddenly cause this situation. The website has websocket communication, and it is unknown whether it is caused by this, but the majority of the time is normal.

I want to use chrome developer tool analyze the problem, but it not work, it should be due to the CPU having reached 100%, so, is there any other way to help me analyze what is causing it? thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What do you mean with “it not work”? And have you tried other browsers, or other devices?

Comment: Use devtools memory profiler.